# How do I Call Native Code From (MIT) Scheme?

Tags: scheme, ffi, native-code, mit-scheme

How do I call a native function (say, [`MessageBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645505.aspx)) from Scheme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MIT Scheme has a FFI for Windows. Check out the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-ref/Foreign-function-interface.html#Foreign-function-interface).

Comment: Thanks for the link. Interestingly, I'm using an old version of STk, and for some reason some of the functions don't even exist. `find-module` does exist, though, but when I try `(find-module 'kernel32)` or `(find-module 'kernel32.dll)`, I get "module does not exists"... any ideas?